# Show text on hover / click to write into HTML Table

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angularjs-directive

I've HTML table connected with component field `gameArray` and I would:

- show 'H' when user's cursor is located above TD (:hover) and it's analogue field in `gameArray` is empty string,
- fill `gameArray` field after click.

I've coded it, and it works perfectly in Firefox, and with some problem in Chrome. The problem is: when I clicked on column 0 or 1, in the next column will be displaing 'H'.

It will be nice to see Yours advices.
Regards!

Working app example:

https://angular-idfr1g.stackblitz.io

`app.component.html`

```
    <hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
      <table>
        <tr *ngFor='let row of gameArray; let i = index'>
          <td *ngFor='let column of gameArray[i]; let j = index'
              (click)="selectFieldHandler(i, j)"          
              appHoverDirective>{{ gameArray[i][j] }}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

`app.component.ts`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  gameArray = [
    ['', '', ''],
    ['', '', ''],
    ['', '', '']
  ];

  selectFieldHandler(row: number, col: number): void{
    this.gameArray[row][col] = "clicked";
  }
}
```

`hover-directive.ts`

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appHoverDirective]'
})
export class HoverDirective implements OnInit {

  markToDisplay: string = 'H';
  currentElement;

  constructor(
    private _element: ElementRef
  ){}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  @HostListener('mouseenter') onMouseEnter() {
    if ( this._element.nativeElement.textContent === "" ) {
      this.currentElement = this._element.nativeElement;
      this._element.nativeElement.style.color = '#00274a96';
      this._element.nativeElement.textContent = this.markToDisplay;
    }
  }

  @HostListener('mouseleave') onMouseLeave() {
    if ( this._element.nativeElement === this.currentElement ) {
      this._element.nativeElement.textContent = '';
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

I needed to clear td textContent in directive after click.

```
  @HostListener('click') onMouseClick() {
    if ( this._element.nativeElement === this.currentElement ) {
      this._element.nativeElement.textContent = '';
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the content could be interfering with the model binding.

Try making the change in your game array. Your directive will just fire an event and add a class if you want to update the style.

Also, if you don't want to put temporary data in your game array, you could have the class for styling also use a `:before` pseudo-element class to insert the 'H' character.

```
.hover-class:hover{
  color: #00274a96; // This makes no sense, colors are three or six hex digits
}
.hover-class:hover:before{
  content:"H";
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately css content didn't help, but thank You for proposition.